# Java Web Start Security errors

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm migrating program from JApplet to Java Web Start and I have security problems. 
My program is signed with my company's certificate and I also added my site to exception list in Java Control Panel but it still gives me this error:

[image]

My Java Exception Site list:

[image]

My JNLP file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://10.13.3.68:8000/"
      href="myapp.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>My app</title>
    <vendor>My Company</vendor>
    <description>My description</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+"/>
    <jar href="myapp.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="myappResources.jar"/>

  </resources>
  <application-desc 
      main-class="MainForm"
  />
</jnlp>
```

I use java 1.8.0_73. Jar files were properly signed by `jarsigner`. Do you have any idea how to launch the app with Web Start without this error? HTTP server is on my local PC. When I tried small "Hello World" like apps(they weren't even signed!) with JNLP - they worked. I don't know why I get error with this program.

Comment: Is your company's certificate issued by a CA that is known to your locally installed JRE?

Comment: Yes, CA is known to JRE.

Comment: What does 'More Information' provide?

Comment: It redirects me to [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml). There is nothing more than I did to prevent this error, but it still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing my jar manifest file attributes:

```
Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

And adding these lines to my JNLP file:

```
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
```

It started working.

The problem was probably that I had

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

in my manifest file and I didn't have proper attribute set in JNLP file.

Second problem was that I forgot to change codebase in my manifest file - I had specific IP there that I was not using anymore.

Comment: I don't know if it's obligatory, but I checked my app and there are "Codebase: *" and "Permissions: all-permissions" in the resources jar manifest.

Comment: I found that only the jar containing the main class needs the `Codebase` and `Caller-Allowable-Codebase` config. Second you can reference all other jars in the same manifest file by defining `Class-Path`.